# Vector-space, Linear algebra, Span of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

**Question:** Will a set of all linear combinations of the basis of a vector space give the span of that vector space?

This is what I have understood from the meaning of the span of a vector space:

> Example: Say we have a vector space V, and it has 2 basis with
> dimension 3 as follows  $$\{a,b,c\} \quad ; \quad \{d,e,f\} $$ Then
> span of $$V=\{ x_1(a)+x_2(b)+x_3(c); x_i \in \mathbb{R}\} \cup
> > \{x_1(d)+x_2(e)+x_3(f);x_i \in \mathbb{R}\}$$
>
> That is, span of V is the set of all linear combinations that can be
> formed with all the basis of V.

**Question:** Am I correct in understanding what a span of a vector space is?

Comment: Yes: you have correctly stated the definition of the span of a set of vectors; and by definition of basis, the span of a basis is the entire vector space.

Answer (score 1):

You've sort of understood the definition, I think. The definition is:

> Suppose $V$ is a vector space, and $S \subseteq V$ is finite. If $S = \{v_1, \ldots, v_k\}$, then
> $$\operatorname{span}(S) = \{a_1 v_1 + \ldots + a_n v_n : a_1, \ldots, a_n \text{ are scalars}\}.$$
> That is, $\operatorname{span}(S)$ is the set of linear combinations of vectors in $S$.

There is a variant of the above definition for infintie sets, but it's a reasonable assumption that you haven't seen that yet (it isn't often introduced in introductory linear algebra).

Note that $V$ is (often) infinite. We don't usually have call to talk about the span of an entire vector space. For this reason, I don't think you're interpreting the word "span" as you should.

A basis is an example of a *spanning set*, meaning a set $S \subseteq V$ whose span is equal to $V$. That is, as you say,

> [The] set of all linear combinations of the basis of a vector space give[s] the ... vector space

This is a true statement, and indeed is one of the two properties a finite set must obey in order to be a basis (the other being linear independence).

Note that you don't need multiple bases to recover all of $V$. Pick any basis $B$ you like, and $\operatorname{span} B = V$. If you pick another basis $B'$, then we still have $\operatorname{span} B' = V$. That is, every vector in $V$ can be expressed as a linear combination of vectors in $B$, or alternatively as a linear combination of vectors in $B'$. The coefficients of the vectors may change, but we can represent all vectors in $V$ with $B$ and we can represent all vectors in $V$ with $B'$. Choosing the right basis for the given problem can often greatly simplify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The span of any basis of any vector space is the whole space. On the other hand, the span of any set of vectors of a vector space is the set of all linear combinations of elements from that set.